# Firebase pagination limitToFirst() vs limitToLast()

Tags: android, firebase, pagination, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to implement Firebase in android, I have few queries in that, I would be glad if you would help me into this. Getting bit confused in it. So here is my question.

I am showing Firebase chat in `listview` in which I want to only load 1st 100 messages from firebase after that User will do `pull-to-refresh` then load 1st 200 messages and so on.

[image]

For that I am looking in `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()` not getting idea which one is better.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I would like to have your answer to this, that would be really precious for me.

Answer (score 5):

I did almost same thing in this way:

In your class (I assume that is an Activity), create a member variable of `Query` type:

```
private Query queryChat;
```

In the `onStart` method, start doing the query:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // initialize your value event listener

    queryChat= mFirebaseDatabaseReference.
            .orderByChild("timestamp")
            .limitToLast(pageSize);
    queryChat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(yourValueEventListener);

}
```

`pageSize` is an `int` variable and here has to be set to 100.

Doing in this way, you are first making an ascending order of your messages (so, the first messages in the resulting ordered list are the oldest), and then you are picking the last `pageSize` messages (so, the `pageSize` last in order of time). So, you will get the first (in order of time, starting from the newest) `pageSize` messages.

I'm supposing that you already have implemented a `ValueEventListener` here. Also, `timestamp` is a field in firebase message in which you stored the Timestamp in milliseconds of your message.

Now, define a method in your class like this:

```
private void loadMoreItems() {

    queryChat= mFirebaseDatabaseReference.
            .orderByChild("timestamp")
            .endAt(messageList.get(messageList.size()-1).getTimestamp())
            .limitToLast(pageSize);
    queryChat.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(yourValueEventListener);
}
```

The `messageList` here is an ArrayList that stores the chat messages, and is filled inside the ValueEventListener, when you get the messages from firebase.

Here, I'm telling to firebase to do the ascending order (as before), but picking only those items with timestamp <= the last item already visible to the user.(`.endAt(messageList.get(messageList.size()-1).getTimestamp())` is telling to firebase exactly this), and finally `limitToLast` as before.

And now you can call this method (`loadMoreItems`) whenever you want (in your case, when the user do pull to refresh).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I want to load latest 100 messages then if user pull to refresh the load 200 latest messages and so on, which one would be best for that case.

Comment: What do you mean by "which one would be best for that case"?

Comment: @ Valentino I want to knw which one to use in my case?

Comment: It depends on how you do order orderByChild. As you can see in this answer, it's pretty straightforward to use limitToLast in conjunction with orderByChild and endAt

Comment: Hi, @valentinoS. I've tried to follow your aproach, but I always get the same items... I've typed my problem in a new thread. You are wellcome to come and help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997375/firebase-android-pagination-load-always-same-items

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
int mPageEndOffset = 0;
int mPageLimit = 10;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    connectDetector = new ConnectDetector(getActivity());
    if(connectDetector.getConnection()) {

        alanRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL).child(EventChatActivity.SuperCateName + "/ " + eventDetail.getCategory_name() + "/ " + eventDetail.getEvent_title() + "/ " + EventChatActivity.eventID).child("StadiumChat");
        alanQuery = alanRef.limitToFirst(mPageLimit);
        userName = MyApp.preferences.getString(MyApp.USER_NAME, null);

        EventChatActivity.eventID).child("StadiumChat");
    }
}
```

This will fetch records of latest 10 messages from firebase.