# Firebase android pagination load always same items

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I'm trying to do a pagination in firebase. I've followed this approach ([Firebase pagination limitToFirst() vs limitToLast()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159878/firebase-pagination-limittofirst-vs-limittolast)) but I can't get a correct pagination items from firebase, always get the same 3 items.

**This is the problem with the code below:**

I have 12 items in my firebase database.
I retrieve the 3 elements with the first load items, and when I try to load more items, I always get the same elements that I got in the first load.

I've tried with:
postList.size()-1).getTimestamp().toString()
and
postList.size()-3).getTimestamp().toString()
but always get the same data

```
private ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();
private Query allPostsQuery;
private final static int PAGESIZE = 3;
```

//First load items when start

```
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new WallAdapter(postList, getFragmentManager(), getActivity(), navigation, mListener, WallFragmentOwn.this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if(dy > 0) {
            visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    loadMoreItems();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

//Load more

```
public void loadMoreItems(){
            allPostsQuery = FirebaseUtil.getPostsRef().orderByChild("timestamp")
                        .endAt(postList.get(postList.size()-1).getTimestamp().toString())
                        .limitToLast(PAGESIZE);
            allPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){
                        return;
                    }
                    dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = postSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        post.setUid(postSnapshot.getKey());
                        postList.add(post);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

        }
```

**UPDATE 1**
I understand that I need to do the .endAt() with the same type that I have in Firebase database. This is my code know:

//POJO CLASS

```
      private HashMap<String, Object> timestampCreated;


public Post(String text, HashMap<String, Object>  timestampCreatedObj) {
    this.text = text;
    timestampCreatedObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    timestampCreatedObj.put("date", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    this.timestampCreated = timestampCreatedObj;

}

 @Exclude
    public long getCreatedTimestampLong(){
        return (long)timestamp;
    }
```

My Query:

```
allPostsQuery = getBaseRef().child("posts").orderByChild("timestamp")
            .endAt(postList.get(postList.size()-1).getTimestampCreatedLong())
            .limitToFirst(PAGESIZE);
```

I Set the timestamp in Firebase in this way:

```
      HashMap<String, Object> timestamp = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    timestamp.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

    Post newPost = new Post(postText, timestamp);
    postsRef.push().setValue(newPost);
```

**JSON FIREBASE**

```
{
  "-Kt8GeVfyiebF8XhUUkL" : {
    "text" : "0",
    "timestampCreated" : {
      "date" : 1504467921811
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Change the tag inside orderByChild and know, is working pagination.

```
orderByChild("timestampCreated/date")
```

Comment: From quickly scanning the code it looks like it should page backwards through your nodes. But it's hard to be certain, because there are a lot of piece we can't see here. Can you share the [**minimal, compiling** code and JSON that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that I can give it a spin? You can get the JSON by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). For the code: think of something that only exercises the Firebase API you're asking about. Android is likely not needed.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. I'm some days with this and I haven't a simple pagination with Firebase. I did for you a simple app that replicate my problem, you can create the json from a button in the app. Only need set the firebase side to work. I give you a link to my github project, in the readme you can find the json. If you need something more, please, let me know. I'm really apreciaty for your help

Comment: link to my project: https://github.com/salveta/paginationFirebase/tree/master

Comment: `.endAt(postList.get(postList.size()-1).getTimestamp().toString())` That `toString()` looks wrong, since you store the timestamp as a number.

Comment: Yep, ok. I understand that I have in database an "Object timestamp;" and I'm trying to find it as a String. I understand that I need to do a .endAt() with the timestamp object. After some hours working in this I did some changes, but I can't get the correct data. Please, check my question again, I did an update with the code that I have rigth now. Thanks for your time Frank

Comment: I just found the problem thanks to other post from you that I've just find. This is the solution with my update code to do it work. Add this: .orderByChild("timestampCreated/date")